# How play mp3/audio files in Racket?

Tags: audio, scheme, racket, mp3, wav

I intend on making a cli audio player for racket, as an exercise to learn Racket, and everything else that would entail this project. I am stuck though how to begin. I can't find any package to play sound files, so I am guessing I may have to make one. How would I go about it?

Comment: This is a good question. I can't find a "play mp3" function anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be one for playing OGG files (that a pretty low level lib). How do I begin with this?

Comment: If you know your way around digital audio, you can use the `rsound` module and write your own implementation. Alternatively, you can do FFI with PortAudio or OpenAL.

Comment: &noblesiks consider answering your own question

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is `#lang video` ([website](https://lang.video/)). It provides a high level interface into audio playback. Allowing you to do something like:

```
#lang video
(clip "file.mp3")
```

Since you want to make a little command line player you might also want to take a look at its small [preview tool](https://github.com/videolang/video/blob/master/video/player.rkt).

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing this the hackish way by calling a shell script via racket, not ideal at all. For reference, putting the code here.

```
; This creates the initail rsound
; for a song, this rsound is passed around
; so the whole song doesn't have to be
; decoded from the file everytime.
(define (play filepath)
  (cond [(string=? "mp3" (last (regexp-split #rx"\\." filepath)))
         (system* "./mp3-hack" filepath)
         (set! filepath "curr.wav")])
  (define input-pstream (make-pstream))
  (define input-rsound (rs-read filepath))
  (pstream-play input-pstream input-rsound)
  (values input-pstream input-rsound filepath))
```

And the mp3-hack file just uses ffmpeg

```
#!/bin/sh
ffmpeg -i $1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 curr.wav
```

Yeah, I know. Inelegant, but at least I got it working. I needed it for my hackathon project [MPEGMafia](https://github.com/Hallicopter/MPEGMafia)